# how to add non-latin gnu/make targets to completion list?

Tags: bash, gnu-make, bash-completion

*gnu/make* supports non-latin identifiers (f.e., targets) in makefile.

example:

```
$ cat GNUmakefile
test:
  @echo test
тест:
  @echo test in russian

$ make test тест
test
test in russian
```

but the *bash-completion* with this example completes only one target — `test`:

"make " + <kbd>tab</kbd> → "make test".

how to add non-latin targets to completion list?

---

tested on various list of distributions (debian 5-8, ubuntu 12-15, centos 5-6, mandriva 2008) with different versions of *bash-completion*.

i need support for this feature at least with recent version of the *bash-completion*.

Comment: Please add OS/distribution and version to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus, i've updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i found the solution.

bug in the function `_make_target_extract_script` from the file `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/make`, which returns *sed*-script, which contains line:

```
/^[^a-zA-Z0-9]/             d             # convention for hidden tgt
```

which removes the targets that begins (in particular) with a non-latin character.

such a regexp would be more appropriate, in my opinion (see [this](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq3.html#s3.7)):

```
/^[^[[:alnum:]]]/             d             # convention for hidden tgt
```

---

if you can not edit the `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/make`, you can add to `~/.bashrc` such lines (based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216806/110559)):

```
_completion_loader make
eval "$(type _make_target_extract_script | sed '1d;s/a-zA-Z0-9/[[:alnum:]]/')"
```

---

**update**

i submit a [bug report](https://alioth.debian.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=315118&group_id=100114&atid=413095) (unfortunately, registration required).

Comment: Submitting a bug in the regular Debian BTS is probably much preferable to an Alioth bug.

Answer (score 1):

The direct solution would be to switch to `zsh` with `oh-my-zsh` if you want to see this working.

[image]

`Bash` is known for various bugs and unsupported features. `zsh` works 2 times faster and almost fully compatible with `bash` POSIX shell, so most of your `bashrc` and `shell` scripts will work the same way with either `bash` and `zsh`.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but *zsh* does not suit me, f.e., because of security hole: the **default** ability to create aliases for `\command` and `/path/to/command`.